# AES 256 encryption can't get IV from byte array correctly

Tags: c#, cryptography

I'm trying to create a handler class for AES 256 encryption, and I saw that it is apparently secure to use a different IV for each encryption, and to put it at the beginning of the byte array. So I tried to add that but it can't get it correctly. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace EncryptionTest
{
    public class Aes256Handler
    {
        private byte[] key;

        public Aes256Handler(byte[] key)
        {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public string EncryptString(string plaintext)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext)));
        }

        public string DecryptString(string encryptedtext)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptedtext)));
        }

        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] bytes)
        {
            if (bytes == null || bytes.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid bytes");
            }

            if (key == null || key.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid encryption settings");
            }

            byte[] encrypted;

            try
            {
                using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
                {
                    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    aes.Key = key;
                    aes.KeySize = 256;
                    aes.BlockSize = 128;
                    Util.PrintByteArray(aes.IV);
                    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        ms.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);

                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                        }

                        encrypted = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to encrypt data");
            }

            return encrypted;
        }

        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] bytes)
        {
            if (bytes == null || bytes.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid bytes");
            }

            if (key == null || key.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid encryption settings");
            }

            byte[] decrypted;

            try
            {
                using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
                {
                    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    aes.Key = key;
                    aes.KeySize = 256;
                    aes.BlockSize = 128;
                    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                    ms.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);
                    Util.PrintByteArray(iv);
                    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, iv);

                    using (ms)
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(cs))
                            {
                                decrypted = new byte[iv.Length];
                                br.Read(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length - iv.Length);
                            }
                        }

                        decrypted = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to decrypt data");
            }

            return decrypted;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Plain text: Hello World!
198 66 49 215 139 95 165 131 201 119 136 16 45 170 140 70 
Encrypted text: �B1׋_���w�-��F?�����8#*�����
239 191 189 66 49 215 139 95 239 191 189 239 191 189 239 191 
Decrypted text: �B1׋_���w�-��F?�����8#*�����
```

A solution to my issue and other advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For starters, UTF 8 is **not** suitable for taking an array of bytes with *arbitrary* values and turning that into a string. But that's what encryption hands you. You should be looking for something like Base64 encoding instead.

Comment: Should I Base64 encode a string before encryption and Base64 decode it after decryption? I remember having to do that in Java AES. I don't see any methods that let me convert a string to a Base64 byte array.

Comment: No. Precisely the opposite. You have `string -> bytes -> encryption -> bytes -> string`. That first conversion is from an *arbitrary string* to a sequence of bytes. UTF8 or anything else within the Text Encoding area of the framework would be right for that. But encryption can take in an arbitrary set of bytes and gives no guarantees about the set of bytes it returns. They really are arbitrary so you cannot claim that they represent valid UTF8 sequences. That's where you'd be looking for Base 64 in `System.Convert` (and you have to reverse the thinking for decryption). But this isn't "the" fix

Comment: There are also issues with using a `BinaryReader` on the decrypt side, over-writing the contents of the decryption with the input contents by calling `decrypted = ms.ToArray()` and there's a padding issue as well I haven't worked out yet.

Comment: I changed EncryptString to:

return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext)));

and now it returns something along the lines of this:

UHuq/JavTiRF5XNobLdA+BTFBfEE7z+eLgtQT14SY/Y=

so I think that was a step in the right direction.

Comment: Are these the correct conversions:

https://i.imgur.com/4A0GemQ.png

Comment: In your decrypt method you are overriding the decrypted byte array by doing a ms.ToArray()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have included a working version of the code provided below:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace EncryptionTest
{
    public class Aes256Handler
    {
        private byte[] key;

        public Aes256Handler(byte[] key)
        {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public string EncryptString(string plaintext)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext)));
        }

        public string DecryptString(string encryptedtext)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedtext)));
        }

        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] bytes)
        {
            if (bytes == null || bytes.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid bytes");
            }

            if (key == null || key.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid encryption settings");
            }

            byte[] encrypted;

            try
            {
                using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
                {
                    aes.Key = key;
                    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        ms.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);

                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        }

                        encrypted = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

            return encrypted;
        }

        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] bytes)
        {
            if (bytes == null || bytes.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid bytes");
            }

            if (key == null || key.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid encryption settings");
            }

            byte[] decrypted;

            try
            {
                using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
                {
                    aes.Key = key;
                    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                    ms.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);
                    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, iv);

                    using (ms)
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            decrypted = new byte[bytes.Length - iv.Length];
                            var decryptedCount = cs.Read(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);
                            decrypted = decrypted.Take(decryptedCount).ToArray();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

            return decrypted;
        }
    }
}
```

The main changes that were made were to use Convert.ToBase64String and Convert.FromBase64String when dealing with the encrypted byte array. I also removed the unnecessary declaration of parameters against the AES object as it was just setting the default values and I removed the unnecessary decrypted = ms.ToArray() from the decryption method.

Something else that it important is that when doing the decryption you want to get the number of bytes read. With the padding that is added due to block size for encryption without trimming your decrypted byte array you will find that you will end up with 0's at the array due to the padding.

Comment: There is no method called Take for byte arrays.

Comment: That is an extension method that is part of System.Linq. Just add the using System.Linq; statement.

Comment: I get an error at the end of the using statement for the MemoryStream.

Comment: InvalidOperationException. There isn't any other information besides that.

Comment: There should be a message with the exception.

Comment: There is no message. It just comes from CapiSymmetricAlgorithm.DepadBlock

Comment: I have been able to reproduce the error. The easiest way to get around it is to avoid setting the aes.Mode, aes.KeySize and aes.BlockSize in the encrypt and decrypt methods. You are setting them to the same as the default values so they are unnecessary. I am not sure why but removing explicitly setting the values fixes the issue.

Also as a side note since you are catching the exception for the purpose of logging it would be better practice to do Console.WriteLine(e); throw;. That way the full exception is written to the console and the original exception is thrown rather than a wrapped one.

Comment: The Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace); bits are temporary. I'm gonna remove them so the other exceptions can go instead, having a lack of information for security.

Comment: Yeah, removing the KeySize and BlockSize bits worked. Am I still using AES 256 though?

Comment: Yeah. You can see the key size if you put a breakpoint in and check the keysize property on the aes object you should see it says 256.